# mysql problem : component misspelt in sources.list

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I can't remember how I arrived to this phase, but I remember that's I needed to install npm packages where wasn't possible so I tried many solution to fix that problem but I didn't one.
So now I can't even update. I'm under ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

[this is a screenshot of the apt-get update output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLFFQ.png)

plz help me !

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you edit your question to put the screen copy in char form (less space required + easier to read and copy parts)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in `etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty.list` that is generating the `component misspelt in sources.list` error message is for a trusty repository and you are using bionic (18.04). Remove the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` the contains the string `http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu trusty` by preceding it with a `#` character in order to turn it into a comment. Please don't remove the valid line that contains `http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic`.

Open `etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty.list` for editing with the following command:

```
sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty.list
```

Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Then try `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: please check the screenshot of my sources.list file, it doesn't contains the line that i must comment it:
https://imgur.com/gallery/mO6sIQa

Comment: @MoezBenRebah I think the line that should be commented out is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`. If it's not there it must be in some other file in the `/etc/apt/` directory, and you'll have to search the files in `/etc/apt/` manually until you find it.

Comment: I found here : /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty.list, the last line and comment it :
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
**# deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty mysql-5.7-dmr**
-------------
now I can update but when I tried to upgrade it asks to delete a package "libevent-core-2.1-6", should I delete it ???

Comment: [@karl](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel) why that package "libevent-core-2.1-6" is no longer required ?

Comment: mysql-server-5.7 depends on libevent-core-2.1-6, so if you have mysql-server-5.7 installed then you need libevent-core-2.1-6, otherwise you probably don't need it.